# How to implement specific font style in Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have defined my styles in a CSS style sheet, and everything looks as expected in Chrome and Safari. But I loose the styles when I open my project in Internet Explorer. I tried to define the style directly in the HTML document but it still doesn't work. Do I need to implement some IE specific style definition? Or any other ideas how I can solve this?
Here is the css for my "submenu-btn":

```
.submenu-btn {
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-family: avenir;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border : none;
  border-bottom: solid 0.5px lightgray;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
  border-radius: 0px;
  bottom: 5px;
  position: static;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Can you also add the code of how you added the font to the website. The `@font-face` rules I mean

Comment: Can it be that the font file type isn't supported by IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Probably. I am very new to this... so I haven't used font-face rules before. I will read about it now. But I loose my other styles as well (like text position and font size). Is that also related to the font-face? And how do I know what kind of font style I am using?

Comment: The font file extensiontype is like `.otf` or `.ttf` IE doesn't support that much https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp. the `text-align` and `font-size` properties are somewhat related but they work the same in all browser. You are also just using `px` and not any other unit type so that can't be the problem. But how do you reference the font if you don't use `@font-face`?

Comment: I just typed font-family: avenir in the css and it worked on Safari and Chrome... maybe that's some built in fonts for the browsers (I have no idea)

Comment: If you just typed it in the CSS and it worked than I guess the font is installed on your machine. Meaning that a other user who doesn't have the font installed wouldn't see the font you want. Maybe you can take a look at google fonts. A Google font that is close to avenir apperently is Nunito http://joelcrawfordsmith.com/closest-font/font/avenir, https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nunito. With google fonts you can import the font you want and every user gets that font so it should be less error prone

Comment: Great! That solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest ways of adding a font to a stylesheet is by using [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/). By using Google fonts you will give all users the same experience no matter the browser.

A browser can only use fonts that are locally available. So when you are using a font that is only installed on your machine a other user will not see that font unless installed. By using Google Fonts neither you or a other user will have to install the font.

This makes Google Fonts less error prone than defining a font by `@font-face` which has some quirks. For instance not every font file extensions is supported by all browsers as can be seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face#Browser_compatibility) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp). But you also need to define the `font-weight` and `font-style` for all rules.

For using Google Fonts there are 2 options. The first is by HTML. Add the following HTML in the head tag:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
```

The second option would be to import it directly into the stylesheet. Add the following CSS somewhere (preferably on top) in your CSS file:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');
```

That way you don't need to import it with HTML.

In both cases you still need to add the following line to apply the font-family to a element:

```
font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
```

The font [Nunito](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nunito) is quite close to the look of Avenir which is stated in the question.